# What Security Measures are needed for online payments?

Tags: security, ssl, paypal

I'm using Paypal Pro and direct CC payments.  What security measures should I take besides SSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at [guidelines for PCI compliance](http://www.bbb.org/data-security/becoming-pci-compliant/checklists/) -- which is all about securing, processing, and storing online payments.  If you follow these rules, you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested reading:

- [PCI security standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/)
- [Dealing with passwords](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2010/07/29/web-password-standards-2/)